docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q) почему не работает?
$: docker images -a                                         
REPOSITORY     TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
<none>         <none>    fbc7da749948   2 hours ago   180MB
<none>         <none>    a7ab17d3bd01   2 hours ago   180MB
<none>         <none>    a20b38f75d61   2 hours ago   180MB
<none>         <none>    40d335919b18   2 hours ago   180MB
<none>         <none>    44d8d1d61a61   2 hours ago   180MB
<none>         <none>    340f2bcd4ba7   2 hours ago   180MB
openvpn-serv   latest    d5dfd7db7d9a   2 hours ago   180MB
<none>         <none>    75e59c0dd9bb   2 hours ago   180MB
<none>         <none>    e64dcdc5e4f6   2 hours ago   180MB
ubuntu         latest    b1d9df8ab815   4 weeks ago   78.1MB

$: docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]

Remove one or more images


Что показывает docker images -f "dangling=true"

вон я же написал снизу команды docker images -a

docker images -f "dangling=true"
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE

ваша команда показывает "пусто"

А просто docker images что показывает? Флаг -a показывает какие-то «intermediate images» и вполне возможно что они вовсе не «dangling»

Ой пассиба большое!
